# Conversion error using euro symbol (€) in IBM UDB .Net

Tags: .net, iseries-navigator, db2-400

I'm getting a conversion problem using the euro symbol (€) in a input parameter from a stored procedure. This is the code I'm using:

```
Dim _command As New iDB2Command
p = New iDB2Parameter
p.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
p.iDB2DbType = iDB2DbType.iDB2VarChar
p.ParameterName = "@TXT_VALUE"
p.iDB2Value = "I have 100€."
_command.Parameters.Add(p)
```

The detailed error is:

```
IBM.Data.DB2.iSeries.iDB2ConversionException
Message: A conversion error occurred.
MessageCode: 6107
MessageDetails: Parameter: 4.
```

The SQL code is blank (exception occurs before executing command).

Enviroment:

- Windows 7, VS2010 & .Net 4.0 framework
- IBM DB2 for i .NET Provider (13.0.0.2 - V7R1M0)

Regards!

Comment: It is probably an encoding problem... Probaby the parameter is defined as ASCII, or ASCII is defined as the default encoding.

Comment: The parameter for the stored procedure on the server is probably defined using the default EBCDIC encoding, but with an older CCSID that does not have Euro support. The SYSPARMS data should show the definition of the [including CCSID of the character string] parameter number four.  However by explicitly specifying for example, a CCSID 1144 instead of [a likely CCSID 280 as default EBCDIC encoding] on the CREATE PROCEDURE, then I expect the conversion error should be resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Re-create the procedure, having defined that input parameter explicitly, with a CCSID that has support for the euro symbol; i.e. do not allow the CCSID attribute for the character string parameter to default to what is probably an EBCDIC CCSID for which the euro system is not represented.